# DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type (Model.class)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to inflate a cardView set on a RecyclerView, taking data from FireBase.
My problem is:

> DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type
>     app.technologias8.smartbarprototipo.modelos.Pedido

So they tell me that the problem is on

```
Pedido p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Pedido.class);
```

My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.articulos_seleccionados);

    refMesaVirtual.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listaPedido = new ArrayList<Pedido>();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Pedido p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Pedido.class); //!!
                listaPedido.add(p);
            }
            adaptadorListarPedidos = new AdaptadorListarPedidos(ArticulosSeleccionadosActivity.this, listaPedido/*, nombre, precio*/);
            recyclerViewPedidos.setAdapter(adaptadorListarPedidos);
            recyclerViewPedidos.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ArticulosSeleccionadosActivity.this, "Upss.. Algo anda mal!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

My Model

```
public class Pedido {
private String Nombre;
private String Precio;

public Pedido() {
}

public Pedido(String nombre, String precio) {
    Nombre = nombre;
    Precio = precio;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return Nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.Nombre = nombre;
}

public String getPrecio() {
    return Precio;
}

public void setPrecio(String precio) {
    this.Precio = precio;
}
}
```

```
And my DataBase 

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmt0l.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using your own custom class, then there is no need to iterate to retrieve the data. When you are iterating, you are retrieving some data of type `Long` therefore you get that error. To solve your problem, you need to remove the for loop:

```
refMesaVirtual.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    listaPedido = new ArrayList<Pedido>();
    Pedido p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pedido.class); //!!
    listaPedido.add(p);
    adaptadorListarPedidos = new AdaptadorListarPedidos(ArticulosSeleccionadosActivity.this, listaPedido/*, nombre, precio*/);
    recyclerViewPedidos.setAdapter(adaptadorListarPedidos);
    recyclerViewPedidos.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
      Toast.makeText(ArticulosSeleccionadosActivity.this, "Upss.. Algo anda mal!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to use an adapter and a viewholder, the `cardview` is just a `view`, use `FirebaseUI` and in the xml add a `cardview`, then in the `onCreateViewHolder` inflate the layout of the `cardView`, and you would get cards with data...

Comment: Now it send this mistake: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout... do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Please ask it in another question